# Up-to-date Chef cookbook for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra

Is there an up-to-date cookbook for ruby? I wasn't able to find one on the opscode cookbook site. i.e ruby 1.9.3 or 1.9.2p280.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you'll find one for updating the system version of Ruby, as chef is built on top of Ruby, and would therefore be updating itself whilst running, which I'm not sure is possible.

However, I've definitely seen Chef cookbooks for Ruby version managers such as RBenv and RVM, such as [this one for rbenv](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv), and [this one for RVM](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm). Is this for a Server or an OSX dev box? if it's for the later, then I've found [Smeagol](https://github.com/atmos/smeagol) to be a pretty handy shortcut when configuring machines.

Comment: This is for a ubuntu box in production. I'm willing to use rbenv there. Just a quick question, does that rbenv cookbook install ruby? I'll look into it more later. on the road now.

Comment: Hi @berto77, not sure what your Chef environment is like, but I believe it'll rely on the system ruby that Ubuntu comes with, and the chef gem (which I believe you'll also need to install manually, unless your Chef Server does this for you), and then it'll install rbenv. It looks quite flexible too: options for system-wide install, or user installs, though I'm not sure where you specify which particular versions of Ruby you want installed.

Comment: hi @purpletonic thanks for following up. My ubuntu is clean, and has no ruby installed as yet. I'm using chef server from opscode.

Comment: Hmmm not sure then, as every fresh Ubuntu system I've worked with previously, has had Ruby installed, so that must be a very minimal install. Not sure if there's a 1.9.3 package, but I did find this one from [Brightbox](http://blog.brightbox.co.uk/posts/next-generation-ruby-packages-for-ubuntu).

Comment: hey @purpletonic, no worries. I read through the rbenv documentation. It will install ruby for you, but it depends on ruby_build. I just need to add that recipe to my run list and rbenv does it automatically. I want to provision my server without having to log in for manual labor :). I thought that was the point of chef.

Comment: Ahh cool, good to hear. I think in multi host environments it'll configure everything without you having to login, but that requires Chef server to be configured. That's my understanding anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I just [finished updating](http://github.com/hilary/chef-ruby1.9) Carlo Zottman's [ruby 1.9.x cookbook](http://github.com/carlo/chef-ruby1.9) (noticed this question while having lunch, prior to writing a pull request, lol...)

The only dependencies are the standard build-essential and apt cookbooks from the opscode cookbook site.

As for the discussion about when a cookbook such as this one might be needed, I'm using it to upgrade from ruby 1.8 to ruby 1.9 on my 12.04.01 vagrant boxes *before* using the rbenv cookbook (and various others).

I realize that I ought to be able to use the rbenv cookbook to install 1.9.3, but after futzing with that unsuccessfully for a couple of hours, I realized that I was happier with the source installation anyway, as it makes my whole recipe stack less brittle. And a shell script to rbenv install 1.9.3 as the vagrant user was trivial to write.

### Update

I found an alternative approach that has even fewer dependencies (yes!) I'm using [Fletcher Nichol's](http://github.com/fnichol) cookbooks:

- [ruby_build](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/ruby_build) from the opscode community page
- [chef-rbenv](http://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv) from github (Not the same as the rbenv cookbook at opscode)

Strictly speaking, of course, you could just use ruby_build to install your preferred 1.9 and stop, but I want rbenv as well.

I've included some snippets from my setup (there's more to the Berksfile and Vagrantfile, of course, but these are the relevant bits.) The only truly tricky part is that the local name of the `chef-rbenv` cookbook has to be `rbenv` if you want to use any of the off-the-shelf recipes that include other off-the-shelf recipes from the cookbook, as it refers to itself as rbenv. Berkshelf made that trivial.

[Berksfile](http://berkshelf.com/):

```
group :ruby do
  cookbook 'ruby_build'
  cookbook 'rbenv', git: 'https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv'
end
```

Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = 'chef/cookbooks'
  chef.roles_path     = 'chef/roles'
  chef.json           = {
    'rbenv' => {
      'global' => '1.9.3-p194',
      'rubies' => [ '1.9.3-p194' ],
      'gems'   => {
        '1.9.3-p194' => [
          { 'name'   => 'bundler' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  chef.add_role 'ruby'
end
```

chef/roles/ruby.json:

```
{
  "name": "ruby",
  "description": "Install ruby and rbenv",
  "chef_type": "role",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",

  "run_list": [
    "recipe[ruby_build]",
    "recipe[rbenv::system]"
  ]
}
```

A final comment is that once I figured the solution out, I realized that Victor's answer is likely the chef server version of the same thing. I have only used chef-solo so far, so I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to use two cookbooks: ruby_build and rbenv. In your role (`<proj>/roles/role_name.rb`):

```
name "your-role-name"

description "All the shelves!"

run_list(
  "recipe[ruby_build]",
  "recipe[rbenv::system]"
)

override_attributes(
  'rbenv' => {
    'global' => '1.9.2-p280',
    'rubies' => [
      '1.9.2-p280'
    ]
  }
)
```

Adding this role (preferably before other roles that would require these rubies) to your run list should do it.

To edit a run list:
`knife node edit <node name>`

Don't forget to update the role! `knife role from file role_name.rb`

Lastly, rubyenv may be a slightly cleaner way of managing rubies than rvm.